# How to compare values in a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a line shapefile (st.shp) depicting the streets of the region of interest. It contains a column agadt2005 which is annual daily traffic values. Being a novice PostgreSQL, I am aware that

```
Select agadt2005 As adt from st;
```

return all values (numeric) of adt from st table in Postgres. Also,

```
Select agadt2005 As adt  from st Where agadt2005 >= 500;
```

returns all values greater and equal to 500 (it filtered out the values less than 500). What I need to do is: To compare the adt values by 500 and if adt values are less than 500 then it should return null values against each adt in a same column. For example, in the following figure:

[Basic_query_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cwAF.jpg)

all adt values less than 500 need to be replaced by NULL. Any advice for how to do this will be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE EXPRESSION :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN agadt2005 < 500
            THEN null
            ELSE agadt2005
       END as adt
FROM st
```

No need a where clause at all.

Comment: Thank you! It worked well. Using CASE statement was a solution.